# Google Cloud Platform permissions using filezilla

Tags: linux, wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I'm having a problem when trying to change the permissions of a particular wordpress folder
/var/www/html/wp-content

When trying to chmod, i can only change the rights of certain folders, and i keep having an error message saying :

[image]

I've tried many things like : chmod -R [permissionsettings] [dirname]

Followed many tutorials also, but any of them helps me understanding why i don't have the permissions to some of the folders.. is this some issue related with the ssh key i'm using ?

I used puttygen to create a SSH key and added it to the vm instance

Basically what i wanted to do is, simply change the /wp-content folder permissions to 777 or 775 to be able to import files into it

Answer (score 1):

You are logged in with your Google SSH username. The Apache/WordPress files are owned by another user, typically **www-data** (OS specific).

The simplest solution is the following but there are better ways.

```
sudo chmod -R [permissionsettings] [dirname]
```

Note: I do not recommend changing the directory/file permissions unless you understand the impact. For Apache/WordPress files, you must pay attention to what the permission do and what they protect your from such as hackers.

There are many ways to manage this:

1. add the **sudo** command in front of your commands:

   sudo chmod -R [permissionsettings] [dirname]
2. Add your username to the group that owns the files:

   usermod -a -G www-data your-username

   Note: you must logout and relogin to effect group membership changes.

   I recommend this method as the SSH file transfer tools will now work.
3. Switch to the www-data user

   su www-data /bin/bash

   Note: This method might require enabling and setting a password for the www-data user which is not recommended.
4. Do everything as the root user:

   sudo bash

   Note: be careful as you are now acting as the system's super user.

The key is to understand Linux users, permissions, user and group ownership, and the commands to switch between them.

Comment: The problem is, that was what i tried to do and when i try to change the permission to 777 on all the folders inside /wp-content
I'm doing this for a client so, could this be the problem ? Since i'm not using his account.. Basically what i did was, using the console SSH and putty generator, i added the SSH key to the project and then log in the SSH 
How to be sure also, if i'm using the right ssh connection ?

Comment: @slykikz - in most cases it does not matter which username you are logging into. The key is that the user must have the correct permissions to either directly access the files or can switch to the correct user. Reread the last line in my answer. Then future out how your system is configured.